# Java графы Jung

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!
Использую библиотеку Jung http://jung.sourceforge.net для создания графа. В процессе добавления вершин графа Jung проверяет, если ли там эта вершина или нет, если нет, то добавляет. То есть если написать 
`Graph<Integer, String> g = new UndirectedSparseGraph<Integer, String>();
g.addVertex(1);
g.addVertex(1);`
То добавиться только одна вершина с целым значением 1.
Теперь мне надо создать граф, но вместо простых типов, он должен состоять из моих классов. Теперь, если
`Graph<MyVertex, MyEdge> g = new UndirectedSparseGraph<MyVertex, MyEdge>();
g.addVertex(new MyVertex(1, 255));
g.addVertex(new MyVertex(1, 255));`
Он добавит два экземпляра класса, которые, по логике, являются дубликатами. 
Для избежания этого, я написал функцию, которая по всему ArrayList из MyVertex ищет класс с одинаковыми полями и удаляет.
Вопрос, есть ли в JUNG готовые решения для этой проблемы? Если нет, то как эффективно можно использовать поиск в ArrayList, если его размер порядка 10 000 ?

Comment: Переопределены ли методы equals и hashCode в ваших классах? Почему бы вместо List не использовать Set? Если вы используете List только для поиска дубликатов, то посмотрите в документацию Jung (или исходный код) и поймите, что можно сделать, чтобы библиотека сама заботилась об удалении.

Comment: hashCode не переопределял. При наследовании, он не просит, чтобы его переопределили.

Comment: @stream2006 Кто не просит? Код с вами разговаривает? Если переопределяете equals, то всегда нужно переопределять hashCode.